# Regex / Regular Expression Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to get my head around regex and how to use it to split a string containing a paragraph into sentences.

**Edit:** If i have the text:

```
Hello, my name is Mr. Bob. I am 15.2 months old. Can you believe that? No... Oh well.
```

I want it to turn into

```
Hello, my name is Mr. Bob.
I am 15.2 months old.
Can you believe that?
No... Oh well.
```

Comment: What is your question ? I don't see any, please be specific.

Comment: So what kind of titles are there? Mr. Mrs. Ms., Dr. Md. M.D., PA. ... And what punctuation should end a sentence? Seems like a rabbit hole, and definitely one not tailored to regular expressions.

Comment: I don't want to use NLTK, but i believe its better suited to the task after some research. Punctuations such as ? ! or fullstop. The list of titles doesn't need to be too deep, the common Mr. Mrs. Dr. Miss. Ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need a `.` or `?` followed by one or more whitespaces: `[.?]\s+`. Further, you do not want to split on multiple dots. For that I would use negative lookback:

```
(?<!\.)[.?]\s+
```

Then there is the problem of titles. You can include those in the negative lookback too. The caveat is that negative lookback groups must always match the same number of characters, so we simply use a plain `.` to 'pad' the lookback in the cases where we need it:

```
print re.sub(r'(?<!..\.|.Mr|Mrs|.Ms)[.?]\s+', '\\g<0>\n', s)
   Hello, my name is Mr. Bob.
   I am 15.2 months old.
   Can you believe that?
  'No... Oh well.
```

Notice how we use `.` to pad our lookback to 3 characters. `\.` gets turned into `..\.`, `Mr` into `.Mr`, etc. We need 3 characters as that's the length of our longest lookback: `Mrs`. In the replacement, `\\g<0>` is expanded to the whole string matched by the replacement, not including the lookback.

From here, it should be straightforward to extend the regex to suit your needs. One final point is that I'd remove all newline characters from the paragraph before running the regular expressions. This may not exactly be necessary, but seems prudent as `.` does not match newlines per default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! is it possible to place the next on the next line instead of inserting a comma? Also the "e.g. this" statement is splitting when it is not supposed to.

Comment: I split the string into a Python list. It's easy to turn the list into a newline-separated string, see for example [this page](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/data-types/python-join-examples).

Comment: Greatly appreciate the help Chris, if it's not too much trouble could you explain the lookback you used on the titles? I'm having trouble implementing it on my text file. It always returns titles on a new line

Comment: Check out the Python [regex documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). ``(?<!ABC)`` matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for ABC. If you have further trouble, please ask a concrete question including an example.